# Cannot catch an Exception while authenticating user with HybridAuth

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, hybridauth

I'm creating a WordPress plugin that automatically publishes the post to Facebook when a new post is added to the site. For the same reason user needs to authenticate his Facebook account. The code I use for this purpose is:-

```
try {

        $fp_hybridauth  = new Hybrid_Auth( $hybrid_config );

        $fp_hybridauth->authenticate( "facebook" ); //this function does the job of authenticating user and it is causing the exception to be thrown 

        update_option( "session_data", $fp_hybridauth->getSessionData() );

        wp_redirect( site_url("/wp-admin/admin.php?page=facebook-publish&tab=api&fbauth=success") );

    }
    catch( Exception $e ){

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```

This code works perfectly if user permits the permission in Facebook oAuth dialog, but if user denies to give permission, it throws an exception that I can't seem to catch:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Authentication failed! The user denied your request.' in /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(182): Hybrid_Providers_Facebook->loginFinish() #1 /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(58): Hybrid_Endpoint::processAuthDone() #2 /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/index.php(15): Hybrid_Endpoint::process() #3 {main} Next exception 'Exception' with message 'Authentication failed! The user denied your request.' in /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php:147 Stack trace: #0 /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybrid in /home/pramodjodhani/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/facebook-publish/lib/class/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php on line 147
```

The code that is written in the Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php file is:-

```
function loginFinish()
{ 
    // in case we get error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['error'] ) && $_REQUEST['error'] == "access_denied" ){ 
        throw new Exception( "Authentication failed! The user denied your request.", 5 ); //THIS IS LINE NUMBER 86 
    }

    // try to get the UID of the connected user from fb, should be > 0 
    if ( ! $this->api->getUser() ){
        throw new Exception( "Authentication failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid user id.", 5 );
    }

    // set user as logged in
    $this->setUserConnected();

    // store facebook access token 
    $this->token( "access_token", $this->api->getAccessToken() );
}
```

I tried Googling and searching for the issue but I couldn't find anything wrong with this. Sorry I can't provide anything that I got in my research.

Comment: I have this same problem, did you ever figure out what was causing it?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

```
try{
    $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);
    $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($service);
}catch(Exception $ex){
    var_dump($ex);
    return;
}
$user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
```

Exception fires Ok.
But if I move line
    $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

outside the try{} area then I can't catch this exeption. This is quite wierd because this line works Ok and doesn't throw any exeption.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solution was that i forgot about namespace (i was operating inside another one), so the correct code for catch block is:

```
catch(\Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Generally speaking, answers should be more complete than this.  Please see [Answer] for details.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I though my initial answer with correct code that solves the problem was sufficient, i clarified it.